# Finding equal intervals of 2 timestamps

Tags: php, function, datetime, math, logic

I have two timestamps and trying to group the duration into equal intervals for the duration.

```
2013-08-02 00:00:12   to    2013-08-02 00:58:50
```

For example, an interval of 15 seconds should give me the following:

```
2013-08-02 00:00:00
2013-08-02 00:00:15
2013-08-02 00:00:30
2013-08-02 00:00:45
2013-08-02 00:01:00   
....// and so on...
2013-08-02 00:58:45
```

Currently I am using this function that I have created, it works perfectly well however it is extremely slow:

```
function time_active_calculator($from_date, $to_date, $interval) {

$unix_from_date = strtotime($from_date);
$unix_to_date = strtotime($to_date);

$start_time_minute = floor($unix_from_date / 60) * 60;
$end_time_minute = ceil($unix_to_date / 60) * 60;

$valid_times = array();

while ($start_time_minute <= $end_time_minute) {

    if (($start_time_minute <= $unix_to_date)) {
        
        if ($start_time_minute + $interval > $unix_from_date) {
            $valid_times[] = $start_time_minute;
        }
    }
    $start_time_minute = $start_time_minute + $interval;
}
return $valid_times; }
```

The idea now is to get the intervals only for the start and end and use [range](https://www.php.net/range) with $interval being the step. I need to find only the correct interval values for the start time and end timestamps
i.e:

```
2013-08-02 00:00:00   and    2013-08-02 00:58:45
```

and then use range function on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this-

```
function time_active_calculator($from_date, $to_date, $interval) {
$dateFrom = new DateTime($from_date);
$dateTo = new DateTime($to_date);
    while ($dateFrom <= $dateTo) {
        $dateFrom->add(new DateInterval('PT$intervalS'));        
        $valid_times[] = $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $dateFrom = new DateTime($dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    }
    return $valid_times; 
}
```

You need to change `DateInterval()` parameter as per your requirement. If you want to add seconds than it should be `PT$intervalS`, if minuts than `PT$intervalM`.

Comment: This only adds 15 seconds to whatever the timestamp is. I want it so that a minute is split into 4 of 15 seconds each and any timestamp should give the previous interval eg: 00:00:17 should return 00:00:15

Comment: @JCrow: please see my post.